# Relay Modern node does not contain fragment properties

Tags: graphql, relayjs, graphcool, relaymodern

I have the following setup in my React Project:

```
export default class OverviewScreen extends React.Component<any, any> {

public render() {

    return (
        <QueryRenderer
            environment={environment}
            query={OverviewScreenQuery}
            render={this.queryRender}/>
    );
}

protected queryRender({error, props}): JSX.Element {

    if (error) {
        return <div>{error.message}</div>;
    } else if (props) {
        return (
            <div>
                <div>
                    <ActivityOfferList viewer={props.viewer} title="Titel"/>
                    <ActivityTypeListsFragment viewer={props.viewer}/>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
    return <div>Loading...</div>;
}
}

const OverviewScreenQuery = graphql`
query OverviewScreenQuery {
    viewer {
        ...HorizontalOfferList_viewer
        ...ActivityTypeLists_viewer
    }
}`;
```

---

```
class ActivityTypeLists extends React.Component<IHorizontalOfferListProps, any> {

public render() {

    return (
        <div>
        {this.props.viewer.allActivityTypes.edges.map((typeEdge) => {
            let typeNode = typeEdge.node;
            return this.getCardListForActivityType(typeNode);
        })}
        </div>
    );
}

private getCardListForActivityType(typeNode: any) {
    console.log(typeNode);

    return (
        <CardList key={typeNode.__id} title={typeNode.title}>
            {typeNode.activities.edges.map(({node}) => {
                return (
                    <RelayPicturedTypeActivityCard key={node.__id} offer={node} activityType={typeNode}/>
                );
            })}
        </CardList>
    );
}
}

export const ActivityTypeListsFragment = createFragmentContainer(ActivityTypeLists, graphql`
fragment ActivityTypeLists_viewer on Viewer {
    allActivityTypes(first: 5) {
        edges {
            node {
                ...PicturedTypeActivityCard_offer
            }
        }
    }
}
`);
```

---

```
export class PicturedTypeActivityCard extends React.Component<any, any> {

    public render() {
        return (
            <PicturedCard title={this.props.offer.title} subtitle={this.props.activityType.title} width={3}/>
        );
    }
}

export const RelayPicturedTypeActivityCard = createFragmentContainer(PicturedTypeActivityCard, graphql`
    fragment PicturedTypeActivityCard_offer on ActivityType {
        title
        activities(first: 4) {
            edges {
            node {
                id
                title
            }
        }
    }
    }
`);
```

Which should work and give me the correct result from the graphcool relay endpoint.

**The Network call to the relay endpoint is indeed correct and I receive all the ActivityTypes and their activities and titles from my endpoint.**

But somehow in the function getCardListForActivityType() the typeNode only contains the __id of the node as data and no title at all:

[image]

If I insert title and activities directly instead of using

```
...PicturedTypeActivityCard_offer
```

then the data also gets passed down correctly. So something with the Fragment must be off.

---

**Why is it that the network call is complete and uses the fragment correctly to fetch the data, but the node object never gets the fetched data?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is indeed correct behavior.

Your components must, individually, specify all their *own* data dependencies, Relay will only pass to the component the data it asked for. Since your component is not asking any data, it's receiving an empty object.

That `__id` you see is used internally by Relay and you should not rely on it (that is why it has the `__` prefix).

Basically, the prop `viewer` on `ActivityTypeLists` component will have exactly the same format than the query requested on the `ActivityTypeLists_viewer` fragment, *without* any other fragments from other components that you are referencing there.

This is known as data masking, see more in the following links:

https://facebook.github.io/relay/docs/en/thinking-in-relay.html#data-masking
https://facebook.github.io/relay/docs/en/graphql-in-relay.html#relaymask-boolean